# Is $nin db.collection.find() valid

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using mongodb shell and trying to do a collection query within another collection query. Is it valid to do this:

```js
db.watchers.find( { login: { "$nin": [db.results.find()] } } )
```

I'm trying to see if the login id from db.results.find() is in db.watchers.find(). Can mongodb even do that?

Comment: It is not valid due to the return of `find` in the shell, MongoDB does not currently support sub-queries of this nature either, you will have to iterate the result of `find` and build of an array of values

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb does not let you do subqueries. This is invalid.